# Failed to parse json string into JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json

I hava a json string(json object) need to be parsed into js object, but I failed.

json:

```
result = {"user":{"name":"laoqiren","email":"7806494@qq.com","i mage":"https://sfault-avatar.b0.upaiyun.com/888/223/8882 23038-5646dbc28d530_huge256"},"totalTime":1.5,"date":"20 16-09-23","comment":"fffff"}
```

error:

```
Unexpected end of input
```

why?

Comment: Could you post your code, please?

Comment: Pasting it into jsFiddle does work: https://jsfiddle.net/jddyy87m/1/

Comment: `json:` - no, that's just a plain ol' javascript object

Comment: and that line of code is fine - no error

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me

```js
var result = '{"user":{"name":"laoqiren","email":"7806494@qq.com","i mage":"https://sfault-avatar.b0.upaiyun.com/888/223/8882 23038-5646dbc28d530_huge256"},"totalTime":1.5,"date":"20 16-09-23","comment":"fffff"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(obj);
```